Python Pandas Filter and Multiple Conditions
I'm currently analizyng the data of a Household Survey. My goal is to filter the respondants who have a job (their first of their second job) in the private sector AND reported how many hours they work per day in all theirs private sector jobs. I don't care if a respondant has a second non-private sector job and didn't report the hours in that job.
Demonstration.
In "HASAJOB", 1 is 'has a job', 0 otherwise.
In 'JOB1' and 'JOB2', 2 means 'has a job in the private sector', 1 otherwise.
In 'HOURS1' and 'HOURS2', they report their hours worked per day. If 999, they didn't report them.
# import module
import pandas as pd

# assign data
survey = pd.DataFrame({'HASAJOB': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],

                          'JOB1': [1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, None, None, None],

                          'HOURS1': [999, 8, 7, 999, 8, 6, 6, None, None, None],

                          'JOB2': [2, None, 2, None, None, 1, None, None, None, None],

                          'HOURS2': [4, None, 999, None, None, 999, None, None, None, None]
                          })

hasajob = survey[survey['HASAJOB'] == 1] # Fiter respondants with a job
work_in_private_sector = hasajob[(hasajob['JOB1'] == 2) | (hasajob['JOB2'] == 2)] # Filter respondants with a job in the private sector

This is the work_in_private_sector dataframe:
   HASAJOB  JOB1  HOURS1  JOB2  HOURS2
0        1   1.0   999.0   2.0     4.0
1        1   2.0     8.0   NaN     NaN
2        1   2.0     7.0   2.0   999.0
3        1   2.0   999.0   NaN     NaN
5        1   2.0     6.0   1.0   999.0
6        1   2.0     6.0   NaN     NaN

So, I want to exclude 2 and 3 because they didn't report their hours in a private sector job. I don't want to exclude 5, I don't care if they didn't report their hours worked in their non-private sector job. So the filter should cointain 0, 1, 5 and 6.
I have been thinking a way to do that for hours but haven't managed to find one.
I tried first:
work_in_private_sector_and_report_hours = work_in_private_sector[((hasajob['JOB1'] == 2) & (hasajob['HOURS1'] != 999)) | ((hasajob['JOB2'] == 2) & (hasajob['HOURS2'] != 999))]

And got:
   HASAJOB  JOB1  HOURS1  JOB2  HOURS2
0        1   1.0   999.0   2.0     4.0
1        1   2.0     8.0   NaN     NaN
2        1   2.0     7.0   2.0   999.0
5        1   2.0     6.0   1.0   999.0
6        1   2.0     6.0   NaN     NaN

This methos excludes 3, but it doesn't exclude 2, because they did report their hours in one of their private sector jobs

Fixed. Instead of filtering what I wanted to keep, I first indexed the rows I wanted to exclude using loc and then I exclude them using loc

Rather than filtering for the positive case (which you want to select), find out the negative cases (which you want to filter out) and remove them from your base dataframe (work_in_private_sector).
You can change your line as follows:
work_in_private_sector_and_report_hours = work_in_private_sector[~((work_in_private_sector['JOB1'] == 2) & (work_in_private_sector['HOURS1'] == 999) | (work_in_private_sector['JOB2'] == 2) & (work_in_private_sector['HOURS2'] == 999))]

You weren't able to filter out index 2 because in your code for index 2:
((hasajob['JOB1'] == 2) & (hasajob['HOURS1'] != 999)) | ((hasajob['JOB2'] == 2) & (hasajob['HOURS2'] != 999))

The above condition equates to 1 and hence row 2 is selected.
Note: I am using work_in_private_sector during filtering as that's the dataframe you should filter upon rather than hasjob.

You could try this approach:

Filter respondents with a job
hasajob = survey[survey['HASAJOB'] == 1]


Then filter respondents with a job in the private sector
work_in_private_sector = hasajob[(hasajob['JOB1'] == 2) | (hasajob['JOB2'] == 2)]


And after filter respondents who reported their hours in all private sector jobs
work_in_private_sector_and_report_hours = work_in_private_sector[
 ((work_in_private_sector['JOB1'] != 2) | (work_in_private_sector['HOURS1'] != 999)) &
 ((work_in_private_sector['JOB2'] != 2) | (work_in_private_sector['HOURS2'] != 999))
]



I guess this may help if I understood you logic correctly
